# How to access an usercontrol from the code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have an usercontrol  with fck editor for allowing user to add note in my aspx page, which allows the user all kind of text formatting.My need is that I have to access user control from the code behind and collect the content as the same format some one has entered in the fck editor.How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll elaborate on Brian's answer. You need to expose the content from the UserControl by adding a public property:

```
public string Content
{
   get
   {
      return editor.Content;
   }
}
```

Then to get the content from the user control, just called the property from the Page's code beind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string content = this.UserControl1.Content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page, the page code-behind should be able to use it directly like:

```
this.uc1.<uc code-behind properties or methods>
```

So you can expose things from your user control by adding public properties or methods.